# Mapping foreign keys on EF 4 without creating a new Edmx file

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

I created edmx file by unchecking the option for creating entites for foreign keys.So there is no mapping for my foreign key fields. Is it possible to map foreign keys without creating a new edmx file ? If possible How.?  I created .edmx from a database which I had already.I am using VS 2012 .Thanks .

Comment: the problem is that you don't want to recreate the edmx? or you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: @Boomer  how can I able to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5):

Right click in the edmx, hit update model from database. There's a checkbox for foreign keys in there. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That sucks, aside from adding all the foreign keys manually which would be painfull I think you'll just have to delete and re-add the edmx.

It really isn't that bad though, I end up having to do it every few months on some projects and it takes less then 5 minutes even with a db that has a few hundred tables.

Comment: @VeeKayBee open your .edmx file right click select Update Model from Database. In the Add tab click the table that you added then click finish.. I'm also doing this. But sometimes I'm also deleting my .edmx and create a new one. :D But remember to delete the Connection String of your previous .edmx file in the Web.Config because it will create a new one.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If there are any problems with edmx model generation (which can happen if you change the options and try a partial refresh), the simplest way to refresh the model completely is to select everything (e.g. Ctrl-A) and delete the lot from the model.

Then right click the empty model page and select "Update Model from Database", selecting all the tables you wish to include again, along with the appropriate options checked or unchecked (like "Include foreign key columns in the mode").

This sequence tends to cleanup problems that occur if you try to do a partial update. It will of course remove any customisation you have made to the mode (extra navigation etc), but is generally to easiest solution to edmx problems.

Comment: some of my team mates are facing this issue. I will tell them to check this and update you. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can delete and add the model again. I hope that will work. :)